# FluentValidation with nested class, generics and MediatR pipeline

Tags: fluentvalidation, mediatr

I have the following MediatR pipeline:

```
public class FailFastRequestBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse> 
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator> _validators;

    public FailFastRequestBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var failures = _validators
            .Select(async v => await v.ValidateAsync(request))
            .SelectMany(result => result.Result.Errors)
            .Where(f => f != null)
            .ToList();

        return failures.Any()
            ? Errors(failures)
            : next();
    }
    ...
}
```

The constructor receives a list of validators for the current MediatR command.

My commands are structured like this:

```
public class MyCommand
{
    public class Command
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Validator: AbstractValidator<Command>
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Handler: ...
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. The problem is when I have something like this:

```
public class MyCommand<T> where T: is something
{
    public class Command
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Validator: AbstractValidator<Command>
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Handler: ...
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In such cases FluentValidation doesn't recognize that the Validator inner class is for the outer generic class.

Is there any way to make it work?